# WebServer Crashes on STA Thread Join wih axinterop

Tags: c#, multithreading, interop, sta

I am trying to use AxInterop.Mydll.dll in a project. I have called the function in a new thread with STA. Everything goes fine does my work and on return after a second or so Webserver crashes and even on hosting iis is restarted.  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is diagnosable, the web server is making a call into a DLL that was unloaded.  And SBPCCOMM.dll is the troublemaker.  This can happen with COM servers that were not correctly written, it doesn't properly handle the DllCanUnloadNow() call and allows the DLL to unload even through there are still active object references.  This is not an uncommon bug.

If SBPCCOMM is what it looks like, some kind of biometrics program that uses finger-print identification, written by a company in China called "SmackBio Technologies", then the best cure would certainly be to just uninstall this crapware to keep your server running.  If you need it to work then contact the company for support.